codigo php dentro tabla html Javascript no activo (en gris)
tengo una tabla html-javascript con varios inputs y una lista desplegable, dentro de la tabla tengo codigo PHP que deberia llamar a una funcion de PHP para llenar una lista despleglabe Select-Option, el codigo PHP esta en color gris, no se si estoy colocandolo bien porque el select-option aparece en la tabla pero no muestra la lista desplegable no se llena.
Este es el codigo Javascript para hacer la tabla html-Javascript:
if (idarticulo!="") {
    var subtotal=cantidad*precio_venta;
    var subtotalbs=cantidad*tasa*precio_venta;
    var precio_ventabs=tasa*precio_venta;
    var fila='<tr class="filas" id="fila'+cont+'">'+
    '<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="eliminarDetalle('+cont+')">X</button></td>'+
    '<td><input type="hidden" name="idarticulo[]" value="'+idarticulo+'">'+articulo+'</td>'+
    '<td><select  name="id_cuenta[]" class="form-control id_cuenta"><option value="">Seleccione Cuenta</option><?php echo fill_unit_select_box($connect); ?></select></td>'+
    '<td><input type="number" name="cantidad[]" id="cantidad[]" value="'+cantidad+'"></td>'+
    '<td><input type="number" name="precio_venta[]" id="precio_venta[]" value="'+precio_venta+'"></td>'+
    '<td><input type="number" name="precio_ventabs[]" id="precio_ventabs[]" value="'+precio_ventabs+'"></td>'+
    '<td><span id="subtotal'+cont+'" name="subtotal">'+subtotal+'</span></td>'+
    '<td><span id="subtotalbs'+cont+'" name="subtotalbs">'+subtotalbs+'</span></td>'+
    '<td><button type="button" onclick="modificarSubtotales()" class="btn btn-info"><i class="fa fa-refresh"></i></button></td>'+
    '</tr>';
    cont++;
    detalles++;
    $('#detalles').append(fila);
    modificarSubtotales();
    $("#tasa_cambio").val(tasa);

}else{
    alert("error al ingresar el detalle, revisar las datos del articulo ");
}

}
Conexion pdo:
 $connect = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=condominio", "root", "mysq1passw0rd");

Hacer Query a mysql para traer informacion a mostrar en lista desplegable:
//Traer nombre de cuenta para llenar lista desplagable: 
function fill_unit_select_box()
{
 $output = '';
 $query = "SELECT * FROM cuentas ORDER BY nombre ASC";
 $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
 $statement->execute();
 $result = $statement->fetchAll();
 foreach($result as $row)
 {
  $output .= '<option value="'.$row["id_cuenta"].'">'.$row["nombre"].'</option>';
 }
 return $output;
}

Este es el parte del codigo de la table html-javascript para la lista despeblabe, el codigo PHP esta en gris (creo que no lo coloqué bien el formato,como que no reconoce que es codigo):
'<td><select  name="id_cuenta[]" class="form-control id_cuenta"><option value="">Seleccione Cuenta</option><?php echo fill_unit_select_box($connect); ?></select></td>'+

Por favor que podria ser?

si mas no me equivoco, php se ejecuta en el servidor ... que se supone o esperas que haga el codigo php en la pantalla que muestras?

gracias por su respuesta, La lista desplegable deberia mostrar listado de nombres traidos de tabla mysql

ha que bien y que trae, no los trae???

No trae nada, pero el codigo php dentro de la tabla html-jascript esta en gris, no se estoy colocandolo mal que no lo reconoce

si no trae nada entonces deberias de ver si la consulta a la base de datos estra trayedo algo ...

Tal como te indican, puedes usar la función var_dump($result); para validar si el query te regresa datos.

El problema está en el formato del código php que esta dentro de la tabla javascript html, probé con parte del codigo para hacer la tabla javascript-html y el query para llenar el select-option y funcionó, ahora debo hacerlo para todo el codigo

ya resolví el problema, este código esta bien:
if (idarticulo!="") {
    var subtotal=cantidad*precio_venta;
    var subtotalbs=cantidad*tasa*precio_venta;
    var precio_ventabs=tasa*precio_venta;
    var fila='<tr class="filas" id="fila'+cont+'">'+
    '<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="eliminarDetalle('+cont+')">X</button></td>'+
    '<td><input type="hidden" name="idarticulo[]" value="'+idarticulo+'">'+articulo+'</td>'+
    '<td><select  name="id_cuenta[]" class="form-control id_cuenta"><option value="">Seleccione Cuenta</option><?php echo fill_unit_select_box($connect); ?></select></td>'+
    '<td><input type="number" name="cantidad[]" id="cantidad[]" value="'+cantidad+'"></td>'+
    '<td><input type="number" name="precio_venta[]" id="precio_venta[]" value="'+precio_venta+'"></td>'+
    '<td><input type="number" name="precio_ventabs[]" id="precio_ventabs[]" value="'+precio_ventabs+'"></td>'+
    '<td><span id="subtotal'+cont+'" name="subtotal">'+subtotal+'</span></td>'+
    '<td><span id="subtotalbs'+cont+'" name="subtotalbs">'+subtotalbs+'</span></td>'+
    '<td><button type="button" onclick="modificarSubtotales()" class="btn btn-info"><i class="fa fa-refresh"></i></button></td>'+
    '</tr>';
    cont++;
    detalles++;
    $('#detalles').append(fila);
    modificarSubtotales();
    $("#tasa_cambio").val(tasa);

}else{
    alert("error al ingresar el detalle, revisar las datos del articulo ");
}

Igual la consulta pdo funciona:
//Traer nombre de cuenta para llenar lista desplagable: 
function fill_unit_select_box()
{
 $output = '';
 $query = "SELECT * FROM cuentas ORDER BY nombre ASC";
 $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
 $statement->execute();
 $result = $statement->fetchAll();
 foreach($result as $row)
 {
  $output .= '<option value="'.$row["id_cuenta"].'">'.$row["nombre"].'</option>';
 }
 return $output;
}

El problema era que todo eso estaba en un archivo .js (javascript) y desde alli hacia el llamado a la función en php "function fill_unit_select_box()", en archivos .js no se puede usar código php. lo que hice fue dejar todo en un archivo .php y metí el codigo javascript.
Este select option que contiene código php no se puede ejecutar en archivo .js:
'<td><select  name="id_cuenta[]" class="form-control id_cuenta"><option value="">Seleccione Cuenta</option><?php echo fill_unit_select_box($connect); ?></select></td>'+

